# Cisco ISE: "Resource Initialization Failed: Invalid JSON: Current token not END_OBJECT"

Tags: python, json, api, cisco

I am looking to do a PUT operation in Cisco ISE to change an existing network device description using Python. In order for that to happen, you must send a payload with what network device you intend to do the PUT operation on in either XML or JSON. In my case, I am using JSON. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import pprint
import urllib3
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

url = 'https://X.X.X.X:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/ze5abe60-918k-14pq-402x-01507619wf2l'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}
valid_cert = False

payload = {
    "NetworkDevice": {
        "id": "ze5abe60-918k-14pq-402x-01507619wf2l",
        "name": "TESTDEVICE",
        "description": "YAY IT WORKS",
    },
    "profileName": "Cisco",
    "coaPort": 0,
    "link": {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "https://X.X.X.X:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/ze5abe60-918k-14pq-402x-01507619wf2l",
        "type": "application/json"
    },
    "NetworkDeviceIPList": [{
        "ipaddress": "X.X.X.X",
        "mask": 32
    }]
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, verify=valid_cert,
                            auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
result = response.json()
pprint.pprint(result)
```

This Python code returns the following: http response 400, and the following http error:

```
 {'ERSResponse': {'operation': 'PUT-update-networkdevice', 'messages':
 [{'title': "Resource Initialization Failed: Invalid JSON: Current
 token not END_OBJECT (to match wrapper object with root name
 'NetworkDevice'), but FIELD_NAME\n ", 'type': 'ERROR', 'code':
 'Application resource validation exception'}], 'link': {'rel':
 'related', 'href':
 'https://X.X.X.X:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/ze5abe60-918k-14pq-402x-01507619wf2l',
 'type': 'application/xml'}}}
```

Researching the "ERROR', `'code': 'Application resource validation exception'"` (from above) in the official Cisco API documentation simply yields that `APPLICATION_RESOURCE_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION` Occurs when the resource semantic validation does not meets the requirements". That, plus the http response, indicates to me the issue is with my JSON payload.

Cisco TAC/support has advised that the: Profile Name & Network Device IP list - payload fields are necessary...although I am not sure if I agree with this as this is not mentioned in the official API documentation.

Additionally, I have double checked my JSON format/syntax using 
https://jsonlint.com/

It seems correct. I have also tried changing:
`data=json.dumps` (payload) - in the actual request to just data=payload...with no success

Please advise! 
Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you replace `data=json.dumps(payload)` with `json=payload`?

Comment: Hi Luke, no it does not. It throws the same error of "APPLICATION_RESOURCE_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION"

Comment: Hi, I think you need to add a csrf token to your headers you need to do that whenever you update, create or destroy things in ISE